# Why ng2-tree is showing undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using `ng2-tree` https://angular2-tree.readme.io/v3.2.0/docs/inputs plugin

When i input below `json` it is showing as undefined

```
[
    {
        "value": "helper",
        "name": "helper",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "value": "taxi",
        "name": "taxi",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "value": "Cake",
        "name": "Cake",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Chocolate Fudge Cake",
                "value": "Chocolate Fudge Cake"
            },
            {
                "name": "Carrot & Walnut Cake",
                "value": "Carrot & Walnut Cake"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

with above json my result is as `undefined` you can see them in my provided link below

here is the stackblitz link:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-tree-aouyza?file=app/app.component.ts

Please help me thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure is wrong. The `tree` component received as input param a `TreeModel` and you're having an array of `TreeModel`s at the moment.

Either you adjust your data structure and use a parent `TreeModel` to wrap your current ones as its children, like following:

```
tree: TreeModel = {
  value: 'Parent Model',
  children: [
    {
      value: 'helper',
      name: 'helper',
      children: [],
    },
    {
      value: 'taxi',
      name: 'taxi',
      children: [],
    },
    {
      value: 'Cake',
      name: 'Cake',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'Chocolate Fudge Cake',
          value: 'Chocolate Fudge Cake',
        },
        {
          name: 'Carrot & Walnut Cake',
          value: 'Carrot & Walnut Cake',
        },
      ],
    }
  ]
};
```

Or you iterate over the array in the HTML and use multiple `tree` components. That would look like following:

```
<tree [tree]="t" *ngFor="let t of tree"></tree>
```

For more information see the Github page of [ng2-tree](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-tree) ;)

**Update:**

You still need to adjust the data model the way I suggested but you can hide the empty root node. To do so, you need to do following:

HTML

```
<tree [tree]="tree" [settings]="{ rootIsVisible: false }"></tree>
```

Due to this setting a class `rootless` is applied which hides the empyt root node but only if you've added `node_modules/ng2-tree/styles.css` to your `angular.json` or you've added a custom implementation for that class.

You can find the settings doc [here](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-tree#settings).

Comment: If I want 3 main categories(parents) then there is no possibility with ng2-tree? Is it ?

Comment: now it is coming a 3 node but still undefined you can see here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-tree-aouyza?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Because you need to adjust your model to be a `TreeModel` as I've suggested in the beginning of my answer. If you do so, it'll work

Comment: ya understood your point but `TreeModel` structure is like this `{{...},{...},{...}}` i don't know how to construct that kind of `TreeModel` with this type of array `[{...},{...},{...}]` dynamically.

Comment: You could add each of your objects to the roots `children` property. Only the root would be static in that case